using ranksum test within permutation test scipy
I am a bit confused with the definition of the permutation_test function provided by scipy. the following is what I wrote to calculate the p and null distribution
x = disease['Theta']
y = nodisease['Theta']

def ranksum_statistic(x, y, axis):
    stat, _ = ranksums(x, y, axis = axis, alternative='greater')
    return stat

permutation_test(x, y, ranksum_statistic, permutation_type='independent', 
vectorized=None, n_resamples=9999, batch=None, 
alternative='greater', axis=0, random_state=None)

this will return a p-value drastically different (-log10p = 3) with directly using ranksum test (-log10p = 150) (also, if I run ranksum test multiple times, p-value also changes quite a lot)
I am confused as to which one is more appropriate if I want to compare two different-sized arrays (non-parametric) that came from the same distribution (values are different) since no-disease should already be the null distribution.

It's hard to be sure without a reproducible example, but one issue is that the permutation test can't give ever a $p$-value smaller than 1/(n_resamples+1). It's also possible that the handling of ties is different in the two implementations (the help for permutation_test warns about this). Done correctly and with large enough number of resamples, the tests should agree
